# Accessing SEOmatic meta via controller action in Element API triggers HTTPForbiddenException

Tags: plugin-elementapi, plugin-seomatic

I'm attempting to fetch SEO meta for entries inside of an element API, roughly following the advice in [Element API integration](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/issues/312)

Below is the exact code in my `element-api.php`:

```php
<?php

use craft\elements\Entry;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api.json' => function() {
            return [
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => [],
                'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
                    $seo = Craft::$app->runAction('seomatic/meta-container/all-meta-containers', [
                        'uri' => $entry->uri,
                        'siteId' => null,
                        'asArray' => true,
                    ])->data;

                    return $seo;
                },
            ];
        },
    ]
];
```

If I hit this endpoint directly in a browser - e.g. http://my-url.test/api.json - it returns a response exactly as expected. However, if I try to hit the endpoint using an external `GET` requestion with `Accept: application/json` (I'm using https://paw.cloud, specifically), I get back an error exception of `yii\\web\\ForbiddenHttpException`

Is there something about `runAction` inside of an Element API call that isn't allowed? Is there something I need to do to allow this in outside requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to turn on the **Meta Container Endpoint Access** option in SEOmatic -> Plugin Settings -> Endpoints

This is intentionally disabled by default, you need to enable it if you intend to use it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I ended up finding and implementing your other Stack Overflow post related to this before I saw your comment, but I'll try enabling this plugin setting and if it works I'll make yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Enabling "Meta Container Endpoint Access" in the SEOmatic plugin settings did, indeed, do the trick. Are there any pros/cons to this approach vs. your approach in the linked stack overflow post?

Comment: The way recommended in that other post saves you an additional and unneeded XHR so... I'd go with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the pattern described in [How to pull an entry's SEOmatic meta tags with Element API?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/32923/how-to-pull-an-entrys-seomatic-meta-tags-with-element-api) which didn't suffer from the same issue.